# Is it bad to run a query knowing that it's going to return null?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have an order entity that will run through a few statuses as work is performed on it. Each time the page is requested, the backend is returning all the associated data that may or may not be available at the moment, as JSON.

Basically, it's the same URL that gets requested, but a template is switched out depending on the order status, and the backend always runs the same methods to retrieve data. Depending on the order status, some data may be null.

So for instance, a pre-order is a status that indicates the order is not finalized for processing yet. Therefore, no work has been performed. As mentioned, let's say the backend always runs the same queries to fetch data. It might return the "order_information", "work_performed", and "comments". In general, would it bad or expensive to be performing a query that gets "work_performed", even though no work can be performed on a pre-order? It's of course always going to return null during the pre-order stage. Once the order is submitted, there will eventually be data for the order though and would save me from having to write up additional logic on the backend. Not that it's a hassle to write it though, but if it's not necessary, then it keeps the code shorter.

Otherwise, I suppose I would just have to conditionally return data on the backend.

Comment: Technically, the time/expense saved in not returning work_performed could potentially be negated by the time/expense from the conditional statements that would need to run in order to decide whether or not to return work_performed.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of what I thought too. Although I don't have any numbers to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE can be used if a field in the result set might be a null value

Take these three as examples

```
COALESCE(MAX(bids.gold_bid),0) AS max_bid
```

In this example if there is no value (null) for the maximum value for bids.gold_bid then 0 is returned as the value for max_bid

```
COALESCE(bidder.name,'No Bidders') AS highest_bidder
```

In this example, if no one has bidded on the item, "No Bidders" is returned as the name of the highest bidder

```
COALESCE(COUNT(bids.gold_bid),0) AS number_of_bids
```

In this example, if no bids are found (a null value), 0 is returned as the number of bids

Comment: Thanks for the information. It wasn't so much an issue with receiving null, but more along the lines of, is it a bad idea to run the query even though it won't return anything? It's pretty much two scenarios: run all the queries and return nulls where appropriate, or create conditionals that determine which queries to run at that point in the process (which would mean that those queries that are guaranteed to return null aren't run).